# Close The Entry Form

Tags: c#

```
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form_Login());
```

After Login I Wanna Make The New Form Which Shown up After Login Is The Main Form And Close Current Form

I Tried

```
This.Hide();
```

and It Just Hide The Form But It 's Still Running On Task Manager

And I Tried

```
This.Close();
```

It Close The Whole Application Because The Form_Login Is The Main Form

Answer (score 2):

Return a `DialogResult` upon closing your Form1.  Use that value in `Main()` to determine if you should open Form2 or not.  Something like this.

In Form1, perhaps in a button click handler:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

In Program.cs:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
var form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);

if (form1.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}
```

If your Form1 closes without setting its `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.OK`, your application will exit.  If your Form1 closes and its `DialogResult` is set to `DialogResult.OK` then Form2 will open.

---

Edit: **Using this technique for simple logons**

Here's one approach.

Create an enum which describes the result of your logon screen:

```
public enum LogonStatus { NoLogon, UserA, UserB };
```

On your logon screen create a property to store the logon result:

```
public LoggedOnUser User { get; private set; }
```

In the logon form assign a value to the logon operation and close the form:

```
LogonResult = LogonStatus.UserA;  // UserA logged in, for example.
this.Close();
```

In Main run the Logon form, examine the form's `LogonResult` proeprty and process the result:

```
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var loginForm = new Form_Login();
    Application.Run(loginForm);

    if (loginForm.LogonResult == LogonStatus.NoLogon) {
        // Do something because there was no logon, or do nothing here and let your app exit.

    } else {
        // Launch your application form, passing in the logged on user.
        Application.Run(new AppForm(loginForm.LogonResult));
    }
}
```

This example shows passing a `LogonStatus` to your `AppForm`'s constructor to allow you to tailor it the user logged on.

**With the above said though, you should know this isn't really the best way to do this. A more flexible and robust solution would involve taking advantage of Windows directory services.**

Comment: Okai Ur Idea Is Very Good But I Have A Role For Every Account If That Role = 1 open  form 1 if role = 2 open form 2 and so on

Comment: @MuhammedSalah `DialogResult` is just a `Form` property.  You can create your own property (perhaps of an Enumerated type) that specifies a 'Role', retrieve that in `Main` and load the appropriate form.  Let me know if you want me to give an example...

Comment: Give Me An Example Please @JayRiggs

Comment: @MuhammedSalah have a look.