# How to open one window and close another on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have one login window and I want to open another page AND close the login window when user clicks on login button.

I'm using winform and C#.

how do I do it?

Comment: [Like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798822/close-the-entry-form/17798972#17798972)

Comment: If i am not wrong you want the user to login before showing him the main form?

Comment: more like this 
    var f2 = new Form2();
f2.show;

Comment: @saadatrahimi see my answer below. Let me know if you have any confusion in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a main form. Call it frmMain. 
In frmMain before IntializeComponent

```
frmLogin loginForm = new frmLogin();
//Set the dialog result on login form depending on ok and cancel button

//close the application if user wants to cancel
if(loginForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
   this.Close();
```

//else you can continue to call your frmMain initializeComponent method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, here is how your program works.

Upon running, Login Form will show, then after logging in (Login button was clicked!), Login form will close then Main form will pop-up, right?

As my common practice, I don't close the Login button coz it'll exits the whole application. (I dunno why but it does)

So what I do is, I simply hide it.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // some codes here
frmMainForm.ShowDialog();
frmLogin.Hide();

    }
```